# using php for loop for arrays

Tags: php, for-loop

Hi guys I'm kinda new with php and was wondering if anyone can help me with this:
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>
  <?php
    $movies = array("one","two","three","four");
    $result = count($movies);
    for($f=0; $f <= $result; $f++)
    {
      echo $movies[$f];
    }
  ?>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What I wanted to do was to display the elements in the array using the count variable f. But it seems my code is missing something and is showing an error on the browser. Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of $result?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    foreach($movies as $movie){
        echo $movie;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 options:

1. using for loop:

   ```
   $movies = array("one","two","three","four");
   for($f=0; $f < count($movies); $f++)
   {
       echo $movies[$f];
   }
   ```
2. using foreach loop:

   $movies = array("one","two","three","four");

   foreach($movies as $key=>$movie)

   {

   ```
   echo $movie;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

You can also populate index values of the array as follows:

```
<?php
    foreach($movies as $k => $movie){
        echo "Serial: ".$k;
        echo "Movie: ".$movie;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$count = count($movies);
for($f=0; $f < $count; $f++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $movies = array("one","two","three","four");

    for($f=0; $f < count($movies); $f++)
    {
      echo $movies[$f];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interate over the whole array with:

```
$movies_count = count($movies);
for($f=0; $f < $movies_count; $f++) {
    echo $movies[$f];
}
```

or use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($movies as $movie) {
    echo $movie;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$movies = array("one","two","three","four");
foreach ($movies as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Look at :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this(it display value with index)

```
$movies = array("one","two","three","four");
print_r($movies);
```